# Magento 1.9.1 strange behavior with layered navigation

Tags: ajax, magento, layered-navigation

I am having this strange problem with a magento installation 1.9.1.

After template changed and nothing else my previous extension for layered navigation manadev layered navigation has a strange behavior with ajax loading.
When I hit a category and choose a filter with few products everything works fine.
But I have some filters with more than 1000 products each.I have magento default loading up 30 products.
When you hit one of these filters it tries to load all the products in same ignoring the setting of 30 products.

So when I hit a filter or category with 2000 products I get a page with 2000 products loading one by.
This kills my server and of course isn't working.

I tried everything I know but still all products from database are pulled together instead of getting them by portions (items per page).

When I turn off ajax everything is working fine. I use Varnish,Apache,APC,Memcached. I see no error at all except in frontend layered navigation page ESI processing not enabled but this is because we have caches off for development.

So for some reason ajax magento default number of products.

Any help please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Ok.....I'll move to stackexchange....But I think it has to do with code and programming...Sorry about that.

Comment: The message moved in stackexchange :
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114198/magento-1-9-1-strange-behavior-with-layered-navigation

Comment: If it's your code (or code you're trying to fix) then post the code and explain what's wrong and what it should do. If it's just a software debugging exercise then it's not about programming per se so is off-topic.

Comment: ok.I understand...Sorry about that. You are very strict with me...I am really sorry about not having the knowledge to write the code of the problematic file.